# Android : Play WAV created by TTS

Tags: android, audio, text-to-speech

So I am writing an app that creates a WAV file of some spoken Text via the TextToSpeech.  I have confirmed the file is created successfully

When I then try to play it, the app crashes with

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.burfdevelopment.lejostoandroid, PID: 6539
>                                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException
>                                                                                         at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1133)
>                                                                                         at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1118)
>                                                                                         at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1097)
>                                                                                         at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1046)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.burfdevelopment.lejostoandroid.MainActivity.speakWords(MainActivity.java:351)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.burfdevelopment.lejostoandroid.MainActivity.onInit(MainActivity.java:436)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.dispatchOnInit(TextToSpeech.java:814)
>                                                                                         at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.-wrap4(TextToSpeech.java)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection$SetupConnectionAsyncTask.onPostExecute(TextToSpeech.java:2174)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection$SetupConnectionAsyncTask.onPostExecute(TextToSpeech.java:2168)
>                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
>                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

**Code**

```
private void speakWords(String speech) {
        //implement TTS here
        if (speech != null && speech.length() > 0) {

            //
            HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
            myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, "1");
            myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");

            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

            soundFilename = root + "/simon.wav";
            soundFile = new File(soundFilename);
            if (soundFile.exists())
                soundFile.delete();

            if(myTTS.synthesizeToFile(speech, myHashAlarm, soundFilename)== TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

                try {
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(soundFilename);
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Oops! Sound file not created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

I can play the file on the actual device via FileManager.  I have tried playing it later on, I have tried just playing the file.  The datasource line is where it crashes.

**mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(soundFilename);**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following code.

```
// Make sure you are writing access permission in Manifest.
soundFilename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/simon.wav";

mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(soundFilename);

mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: `mMediaPlayer.start();` was throwing the exception. The media was not prepared when `start()` is being called.
You should call `start()` in `onPrepared()` by using a listener.